# Does the failed() condition take arguments? i.e. can I set the condition to trigger only if failing 3 times

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress, azure-pipelines-yaml

I would like to set my `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` task to run with the condition set to failed(). However, I would like to set it so that it only publishes the artifact when the test has **failed three times**.

```
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    condition: failed()
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(testFolder)/$(screenshotFolder)'
      ArtifactName: 'screenshots'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
    displayName: 'Publish Screenshots for Failed Tests'
```

Currently, it is publishing all failing test screenshots, even those that have passed on retry.

Comment: Hi @Kieran, does the answer below resolve your puzzle?If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my knowledge and Microsoft documentation the failed() method does not take any arguments.

You could do a for loop with the ["each"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword) keyword.

I would approach this that I save all screenshots from a given test run to separate folders based on the loop and then with some Powershell scripting and upload only the successful folder or none if all 3 runs failed.